# wrong displaying Textview in ListVIew

Tags: android, listview

I'm new in Android developing and I developping search apk.Search results displaying in custom listview. The layout for list view have this code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Title"
            android:id="@+id/Title"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_columnSpan="3"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Price"
            android:id="@+id/Price"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#ff5f59ff"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Stock"
            android:id="@+id/InStock"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#ff00c000"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Stock"
            android:id="@+id/OutOfStock"
            android:textColor="#ffff0f03"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="ItemId"
        android:id="@+id/ItemId"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_columnSpan="4" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm excepting result sa at img1 , but instead of this I have result like at img2. Can somebody explain what's wrong?

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Price"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:text="Price"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#ff5f59ff" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/InStock"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:text="Stock"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#ff00c000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/OutOfStock"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="Stock"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#ffff0f03"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ItemId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ItemId"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</LinearLayout>
```